# Is there a single function that returns number (when called) depending on which button was clicked

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick, return-value

I have four buttons which i want for them to return a value: 0, 1, 2, 3 depending on the button's index clicked
Ex.when I Click the second button
`console.log(function());` will output 1

Maybe something like this

```
click[1].addEventListener("click", jon);
click[2].addEventListener("click", jon);
click[3].addEventListener("click", jon);

function jon(){return 0;}
function jon(){return 1;}
function jon(){return 2;}
function jon(){return 3;}

console.log(jon());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-attribute here. When you click on the button then you can get the `value` of `dataset` from `e.target`

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

function clickHandler(e) {
  const value = e.target.dataset.value;
  console.log(`button${value} is clicked`);
}

for (let button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler)
}
```

```html
<button data-value="0">button0</button>
<button data-value="1">button1</button>
<button data-value="2">button2</button>
<button data-value="3">button3</button>
```

Comment: This is really close, but how can i get the value of ${value} inside another function?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **another function**, since you want in a single function *Is there a single function*?

Comment: Sorry Not another function , I meant to get the value outside of the function

Comment: Do you want to get `e.target.dataset.value` outside of function that is passed in `click listener`?

Comment: Yes! Something like : const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function clickHandler(e) {
  const value = e.target.dataset.value;
  console.log(`button${value} is clicked`);
}

for (let button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler)
}
console.log(${value});

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach:

```js
let myButtonSet = document.getElementsByClassName("myButton");
let myClickedButton;
    
for(i=0; i<myButtonSet.length; i++) {
  myButtonSet[i].setAttribute('onclick', `clicked(${i})`)
}
    
function clicked(e) {
  console.log(`Button ${e} clicked!`);
  myClickedButton = e;
}

function lastClicked() {
  console.log(`Index of last clicked button: ${myClickedButton}`);
}
```

```html
<button class="myButton">I am button 0</button>
<button class="myButton">I am button 1</button>
<button class="myButton">I am button 2</button>
<button class="myButton">I am button 3</button>

<button class="anotherButton" onclick="lastClicked()">Index of last clicked button</button>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: How do i get the value inside another function? Something like this: function external(){
function clicked(e) {
  console.log(`${e}`);
}
  console.log(`${e}`);
}

Comment: You could store the index of the clicked button in a global variable. I extended the sample accordingly.